# Добавление блока div ломает хедер

Tags: html, css

Не понимаю в чем проблема.

Есть блок nav с двумя дивами внутри. И все, в общем-то, не так уж плохо, но только до тех пор пока я не вставлю ниже, в секции main один див. Каким-то совершенно не очевидным образом он тащит за собой вниз первый из дивов внутри nav.

я подавлен, я опустошен, я почти потерял веру в силу своего разума. Остается надеяться только на ваш разум. Поможете не сойти с ума?

Див-подлец имеет класс first-screen.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
}

i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#meet {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: rgb(0, 180, 217);
}

#me {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 9s00;
  color: rgb(0, 180, 217);
}


/* hiding checkbox */

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu__btn {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* humburger */

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 180, 217);
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}


/* menu container */

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}


/* menu items */

.menu-item {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu-item.active {
  color: rgb(0, 180, 217);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  visibility: visible;
  right: 0%;
  top: 70px;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__box {
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item {
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.first-screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-image: url('../img/fond-mob.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-position: 0 0;*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <title>Tom Saulnier</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div id="logo-block">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user" style="color: #00b4d9;"></i><span id="meet">Meet</span><span id="me">Me</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
          <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
          <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
                      <span></span>
                    </label>
          <ul class="menu__box">
            <li><a class="menu-item active" href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">services</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">resume</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">work</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>

      <div class="first-screen">

      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6c67aca9af.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте элементу `<nav>` свойство `top: 0;` и ваше опустошение с подавленностью должны пройти

Comment: @Deonis, вы не только классный разраб, но еще и отличный психотерапевт! )) Спасибо, все работает и вновь обрел душевное спокойствие ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
}

i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#meet {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: rgb(0, 180, 217);
}

#me {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 9s00;
  color: rgb(0, 180, 217);
}


/* hiding checkbox */

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu__btn {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* humburger */

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 180, 217);
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}


/* menu container */

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}


/* menu items */

.menu-item {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu-item.active {
  color: rgb(0, 180, 217);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  visibility: visible;
  right: 0%;
  top: 70px;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__box {
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item {
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.first-screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-image: url('../img/fond-mob.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-position: 0 0;*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <title>Tom Saulnier</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div id="logo-block">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user" style="color: #00b4d9;"></i><span id="meet">Meet</span><span id="me">Me</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
          <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
          <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
                      <span></span>
                    </label>
          <ul class="menu__box">
            <li><a class="menu-item active" href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">services</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">resume</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">work</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>

      <div class="first-screen">

      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6c67aca9af.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```